# hide/show Search bar in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

In my application is that there is one button in bottom toolbar and when I click it then search bar should be displayed at the top of the tool bar.

How to implement it?

Please provide me solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a searchBar in viewDidLoad and set `searchBar.hidden=YES;` then, in button action set `searchbar.hidden=NO;`. So that you can show the searchBar while particular button was clicked....

Comment: Ya its write.But the space acquired by search bar remains as it is.Means no other view can not acquire its place.its remains white when search bar is hidden.Is there is any solution over this?

Comment: ok... Create search bar while button action was triggered....

Comment: If you call searchBar.hidden = NO; directly on the button action method, it can't be called. It only work with viewDidLoad because you have created method in viewdidload.You need create method again if you wish to call it from buttons action method.

Comment: @GajendraKChauhan put searchBar as a property or global variable in `.h`...sothat you can access anywhere... it is the basic thing... ok....

Comment: I know that, but I am doing it programatically.

Comment: we can do like that in programatically too... Study the apple document for more info..